# My BIOS is lying to me about virtualization being enabled

Tags: android, bios, haxm

So I currently have a Windows PC that I'm trying to set up to do android development. I have a processor and motherboard that support virtualization (intel i5 4690k and MSI Z97A GAMING 6 motherboard).

Whenever I launch my PC into the BIOS setup and navigate to virtualization settings, it says they are enabled. However, when I launch it and try to use the android dev studio emulator with intel HAXM, it says that my hardware supports vt-x but it isn't enabled.

Anyone had issues like this or know how to fix them?

Answer (score 0):

Run (as admin)
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
Download separate installer rather than install thru Android studio
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager